infinite loop happens inside react-native
Below is my code in a small react-native project. Here the line "setcollectionReport(coll);" induces an infinite looping of "console.log(params);" If that setcollectionreport(coll), the looping does not happen. But that process is un avoidable.
Tried to fix it but no idea so far. Could you please anybody help.


function Report({navigation,route}){
  
  const [pairedDevices, setPairedDevices] = useState([]);
  const [foundDs, setFoundDs] = useState([]);
  const [bleOpend, setBleOpend] = useState(false);
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);
  const [name, setName] = useState("");
  const [boundAddress, setBoundAddress] = useState("");
  const db = SQLite.openDatabase('digit.db');
  const day = "'"+route.params.day+"'" //"'2024/08/23'";
  //const dataset = this.route.day //props.route.params.day// navigation.state.params.day;// this.props.navigation.state.params.day;
  //console.log(dataset);
  const params = route.params;
  console.log(params);
  const [collectionReport, setcollectionReport] = useState([]);
  
    let coll = [];
    db.transaction(tx=>{
      tx.executeSql("SELECT id,date,custNo,payMode,paidAmount FROM tblRcpt where date = "+day+" order by id DESC",
        null, (txt,results)=>{
          let len = results.rows.length;
          let billNo =0;
          let custNo =0;
          let paidAmt = 0;
          let payMod = '';
          let billDte = '';
          //console.log(len)
            if (len>0){              
              for(let i =0;i<len;i++){
                let item = results.rows.item(i);
                billNo =  item.id;
                billDte = item.date;
                custNo =  item.custNo;
                payMod =  item.payMode;
                paidAmt = item.paidAmount;
                
                if (item.payMode === 'cash'){
                  payMod = 'C';
                }
                if (item.payMode === 'gpay'){
                    payMod = 'D';
                }
                //console.log(item)
                coll.push({billDte:item.date,billNo:item.id,custNo:item.custNo,payMod:item.payMode,paidAmt:item.paidAmount});
              }
              setcollectionReport(coll);
            }           
           
            //console.log(collectionReport)
        },(txt,error) => console.log(error)
      )
      
    })
    //db.closeAsync(); 

  const renderCollectionReport = ({item})=>{    
    return(
      <View style={{
        flexDirection:'row',
        borderBottomWidth:0.5,
        padding:2, 
        backgroundColor:'#fdfef4',
        height:40   
      }}>
        <Text style={{marginLeft:2,width:60,paddingLeft:2,paddingRight:2}}>{item.billNo}</Text>
        <Text style={{marginLeft:2,width:95,paddingRight:2.5}}>{item.billDte}</Text>
        <Text style={{marginLeft:2,width:75,paddingRight:2.5}}>{item.custNo}</Text>
        <Text style={{marginLeft:2,width:60,paddingRight:2.5}}>{item.payMod}</Text>
        <Text style={{textAlign:'right'}}>{item.paidAmt}</Text>        
      </View>

    )
  }

  return (
    <View style={{flex:1}}>
      <View style={{}}>
        <View style={{fontSize:10,height:50,paddingTop:10,paddingBottom:5,flexDirection:'row',borderBottomWidth:.25,backgroundColor: '#2a053a',}}>
          <Text style={{width:60,fontSize:11,paddingLeft:5, textAlign:'left',color:'white'}}>ID</Text>
          <Text style={{width:75,fontSize:11,paddingLeft:3, textAlign:'center',color:'white'}}>DATE</Text>
          <Text style={{width:75,fontSize:11,paddingRight:5,marginLeft:5,marginRight:5,borderRightWidth:0.25,color:'white'}}>CUSTOMER</Text>
          <Text style={{width:60,fontSize:11,marginLeft:10,borderRightWidth:0.25,color:'white'}}>MODE</Text>
          <Text style={{fontSize:11,paddingLeft:3, color:'white'}}>AMOUNT</Text>
        </View>
        <View style={{ paddingBottom:60}}>
          <FlatList style={{}} data={collectionReport} renderItem={renderCollectionReport} />
        </View>            
      </View>
      </View>
      )
    
}




Move your db.transaction to useEffect so that it will be called only once.

@RohitAggarwal Thank you. Still i wonder how a line outside the db.transaction be affected by it.
